# w2ui grid get records of a search as array

Tags: javascript, jquery, w2ui

Is it possible to get an array with the records of search results in w2ui grid?

Similar to `w2ui['gridname'].records` but only with the visible records.

Answer (score 0):

Found a Solution at the W2UI Documentation:
https://w2ui.com/web/docs/2.0/w2grid.last

First i check for the last search term:

```
w2ui["grid"].last.search
```

then i get all the ids from:

```
w2ui["grid"].last.searchIds
```

in my case the found searchIds were not similar with the recids from the records object, for example searchid -> 6 is matching recid 7 from the records object.

```
w2ui["grid"].records
```